# declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive] error

Tags: c++

I get "decleration does not declare anything [-fpermissive] error";
Here is my code;

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H
#define CAMERA_H
#include "Vector.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Camera
{
    private:
        int id;
        float position[3];
        Vector gaze;
        Vector up;
        float left;
        float right;
        float bottom;
        float top;
        float near;
        float far;
        int type;

    public:
        Camera(int i,string c, string g, string u, string f, string t);
        int getID() {return id; }
        float* getPosition() { return position; }
        Vector getGaze() { return gaze; }
        Vector getUp() { return up; }
        float getLeft() {return left;}
        float getRight() {return right;}
        float getBottom() {return bottom;}
        float getTop() {return top;}
        float getNear() {return near;}
        float getFar() {return far;}
        int getType() {return type;}
};

#endif // CAMERA_H
```

the error starts at "float near;" and continues next 3 lines.

What is the reason of this error and how can I fix it.

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: What's in "Vector.h"?

Comment: @KristianD'Amato Yes I copied correctly.

Comment: @AlanStokes Vector is a class I have create to store my vectors. It stores x,y,z component of vector and do some operations like cross-product

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `near` and `far` with something else, at least for a test, e.g. `near_` and `far_`: I suspect you are compiling with some funny header which defines `near` and `far` to be nothing. In the distant past these two were keywords used on some platforms to deal with pointers of different sizes.

If you want to verify the theory, process the source file with the `-E` option (you may need to remove other options from the compile line, e.g., `-c`): with this option the compiler produces the preprocessed output. If you capture that and look at your class there I'm quite certain that it won't contain the member names.

Comment: changing names has worked but I couldn't understand the reason of the error. what is wrong with 2 different class having same field name? thnx.

Comment: The problem is, the strings are defined to be nothing using the preprocessor, i.e., something like `#defined near`. In the olden days, some pointers were declared as `int near* pointer;` but newer compilers don't understand this notation. Using the macro, the declaration is made to look like `int* pointer;` to the compiler and your declaration become `float;`, not declaring anything. The underlying issue is more scary, though: your teacher hasn't updated his headers since at least 10, more likely 20, years ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_pointer) is a bit more information).

Comment: Defined in windef.h on my system.

Comment: @Caterpillar: Why are you including windef.h?

Answer (score -2):

I suspect "near" and "far" are reserved names somewhere in "Vector.h" or string.
Renaming these variables something different should fix your problem.

Comment: err, no, its not a keyword in c++.

Comment: Which version of C++ you got where `type` is a keyword...?

Comment: Ah fair enough to both of you - I was mistaken. I'll edit accordingly